# Django - Request resolution

Tags: django, url-routing

I would like to know how Django is resolving request urls `urlpatterns` in general.

**My theory:**

Django at some point turns all its `urlpatterns` into list of regexes, and then tries to match them against incoming Request's url.

**Question:**

Am I correct? If yes, can somebody point me out where in source code is this happening?

Looks like there is nothing about this mentioned in django docs, and I feel like I am doing a blind search in source code. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The process is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/). In short:

1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use....
2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a Python list of django.urls.path() and/or django.urls.re_path() instances.
3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.
4. Once one of the URL patterns matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function (or a class-based view)....
5. If no URL pattern matches, or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling view....